# Java 'Date' object size

Tags: java, date, memory

How to effectively determine the size of a Date object in my memory?

Initially I went through this [link](http://floggy.sourceforge.net/datatypes.html) which talks about **9 bytes** for a date object..

I was trying to find it out when I found this link, where it talks about **32 bytes!!!!** for a date object in memory.

[Date Object Size in Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681960/how-many-bytes-of-memory-does-a-java-util-date-object-use)

Kindly help.

Reason for thinking on these lines:
        I am loading millions of objects of a certain class into memory, for some computation. One of the variables in that class is a Date object. I can store the value as a long, but that would require minor quirks in the code. I am thinking on keeping the memory footprint to the least value possible. To do that, I need to know the exact memory requirements in each case to take a call on the same.

Comment: Perhaps explain the issue you're having that requires you to care?

Comment: Consumption in heap space != serialized size, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258120/what-is-the-memory-consumption-of-an-object-in-java

Comment: If you have load millions of Date object, may be you will use int value, correspond to your requirements. Such as max date range or time resolution etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your first link is talking about the size when serialized, you're talking about the size in memory. That's why the sizes are different.

Serialized, as per your link, 9 bytes for the saved long.

In memory, as per your second link, 32 bytes for the long and other objects that allow you to work with the date.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to answer this question is to look at the source code of `java.util.Date`.

It has only 2 non-static fields (Java 1.7.0_55):

```
private transient long fastTime;
private transient BaseCalendar.Date cdate;
```

`long` has a memory size of 8 bytes and `cdate` is an object reference which has a size of 4 bytes. So a total of **12 bytes**.

If `cdate` would be instantiated, it could require additional bytes in the memory, but if you look at the constructors too, sometimes it won't even be touched, and in others it will be `null`-ed at the end of the constructor, so the final result is also **12 bytes**.

This is just for creating a `Date`. If you call methods on the `Date` (for example `Date.toString()`), that **will** create and store an object into the `cdate` field which will not be cleared. So if you call certain methods on the `Date`, its memory usage will increase.

**Note:** Object references might be 64 bit long on 64-bit JVMs in which case memory usage would be 16 bytes.

**Note #2:** Also note that this is just the memory usage of the `Date` object itself. Most likely you will store its reference somewhere, e.g. in an array or list or a field in some other class which will require additional 4 bytes (or maybe 8 bytes on 64 bit JVMs).

Comment: Which version of Java source were you looking at?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Java 1.7.0_55.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your implementation, what you intend to do with it and how you define and measure the size. For example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date d = new Date();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);) {
        oos.writeObject(d);
        oos.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] written = baos.toByteArray();
    System.out.println(written.length);
}
```

Outputs

```
46
```

here.

**Edit**

Using the primitive `long` will always use less memory then any object type (`Date` included). That is fundamentally why Java includes primitives. Finally, using an instance of [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and keeping the values as `long` should give you the flexibility to minimize your code changes.